# Can java.util.Collections.shuffle(List list) return list in the same order as it was "sent to be shuffled"?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist, shuffle

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) say "All permutations occur with approximately equal likelihood." but I do not know if that includes the (however small) possibility of returning the same ordering. I have a method (see below) where during two test runs the list was returned in the original order, maybe.. Other factors may have been at fault, like an anagram could have been selected and the result was a word. The lexicon is ~300,000 words, so I have changed the method to a more suitable test preventing this from being the case.
The method:

```
private static char[] nextScrambledWord(int wordLength) {

    String word;
    do {
        word = "ABCDEF"; //TODO Get a word from lexicon
    } while(word.length() != wordLength);

    ArrayList<Character> temp = new ArrayList<Character>(wordLength);
    for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
        temp.add(word.charAt(i));
    }

    Collections.shuffle(temp);

    char[] result = new char[wordLength];
    for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
        result[i] = temp.get(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am also curious about the method itself. If anyone has a suggestion on how this can be improved, please feel free to share. Basically the method will pull a word of wordLength from a set, and return a char array of the shuffled result. Rather than polling a word of a known length, I have considered breaking the lexicon into multiple sets based on word length.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that the original order is preserved, but, as you say, that is unlikely with longer lists. Try a list with only two elements to see this happen.

Comment: and of course it also gets more likely if the list contains "duplicates".

Comment: @Thilo Thanks. It is important that the word be shuffled out of the original order so perhaps a do while will repeat the shuffle in the event that shuffled order is the same as the original order.

Comment: @gh: Yes, but that won't catch the case that the shuffled word happens to be another word in the dictionary. Think "BEAR" => "BARE". You could test if the result is also in the dictionary, and then repeat the shuffle (or maybe even better pick a new word and start all over).

Comment: @Thilo Yes you are correct, and thank you for your continued attention to this. However for the program this method belongs to, it is not a problem if an anagram is returned as long as the result is not in the original order.